# Background image created in css using linear-gradient & ::before ::after does not expand with webpage

Tags: html, css

I have a page (in codepen) that uses css to create a background of grey squares. The page allows for the creation of a table (grid) that you can click and change the color to make an image. The issue I am having is that when a table is created that causes the page to grow beyond the window size (up down scroll bar comes up) the background image does not expand in kind. I have been tried to find a solution, but I can't seem to overcome this problem. Can this be done in CSS?

Here is a link to my codepen: [CondPen with code](https://codepen.io/pksjw/pen/gvQamN) (*The Pen has the fix applied*)

```
.squares-bg::before, .squares-bg::after {
content: "";
width: 100%;
height: 3500px;    *<-- fix was to change height to 100%, in body too*
position: absolute;*<--   and to change this to fixed*
top: 0;
left: 0;
pointer-events: none;
z-index: -1;
```

}

If I set height: 3500px in .squares-bg::before, .squares-bg::after it kind of works, but I was hoping there is a dynamic solution. Height was set to 100% because I thought it would fill as I grew the window, but that does not happen. Change the value to 100% in the pen and create a grid that is like 60 x 60 and then scroll down. The background does not extend.

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate the body element, have you tried using a div to achieve your desired results? A separate element used to create the background may be more effective than pseudo elements.

Comment: I did not try to use a div. I want to see if I could use css to create a background image and have it be dynamic. But if I cannot overcome the issue I will give the div idea a try. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to adjust the css removing position: in .squares-bg and to set position: to fixed position: fixed; in .squares-bg::before, .squares-bg::after and then to set the height in .squares-bg and body to 100% height: 100%;

Joseph Woolever (JOEY) who is in the Grow With Google Scholarship: Front End Web Development Cohort with me provided the fix. Thanks JOEY!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to set `position: relative` for the `.squares-bg`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.squares-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

.squares-bg::before,
.squares-bg::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.squares-bg::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, black 50%);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}

.squares-bg::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: dimgrey;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px red;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em;
}

h2:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: inline;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px red;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 6em;
  margin: 0 0.25em 1em;
}

input[type="color"] {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<body class="squares-bg">
  <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="15"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="15">
    <input type="submit" value="New Grid">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker" value="#ff0000">

  <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried out relative, but if I did not keep the heights at 3000px that did not continue the background when I expanded the window, for example with a large grid. Thank you for taking a look and for offering a possible solution.

Comment: @pks_jw Sounds like something that can often be solved by setting `min-height: 100%` instead of strict `height: 100%` for the `body`

Comment: I will try that out and do some reading on it. I have only been doing css for about a month, so its all new to me. Seems very powerful. Thanks for taking the time to look and provide feedback!